# OsmocomBB - compile error

Tags: compiling, gcc, arm

I tried to install OsmocomBB on my Ubuntu, I've got gnu-arm-toolchain, but when I'm compiling there is an error:

```
configure: error: in `/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/build-   target':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [shared/libosmocore/build-target/Makefile] Error 77
```

Here is config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libosmocore configure UNKNOWN, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --host=arm-elf --enable-embedded --disable-shared --disable-tests ac_cv_header_sys_select_h=no --disable-tests ac_cv_header_sys_socket_h=no CFLAGS=-Os -ffunction-sections -I/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/target/firmware/include -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = TESTBOX
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.13.0-24-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /home/robert/OsmocomBB/gnuarm-3.4.3/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2349: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2417: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2428: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2483: result: yes
configure:2542: checking for arm-elf-strip
configure:2558: found /home/robert/OsmocomBB/gnuarm-3.4.3/bin/arm-elf-strip
configure:2569: result: arm-elf-strip
configure:2634: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2673: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2680: checking for gawk
configure:2710: result: no
configure:2680: checking for mawk
configure:2696: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2707: result: mawk
configure:2718: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2740: result: yes
configure:2769: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2786: result: yes
configure:2925: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2942: result: yes
configure:2954: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2976: result: yes
configure:2994: checking for arm-elf-gcc
configure:3010: found /home/robert/OsmocomBB/gnuarm-3.4.3/bin/arm-elf-gcc
configure:3021: result: arm-elf-gcc
configure:3290: checking for C compiler version
configure:3299: arm-elf-gcc --version >&5
configure:3310: $? = 0
configure:3299: arm-elf-gcc -v >&5
configure:3310: $? = 0
configure:3299: arm-elf-gcc -V >&5
configure:3310: $? = 0
configure:3299: arm-elf-gcc -qversion >&5
configure:3310: $? = 0
configure:3330: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3352: arm-elf-gcc -Os -ffunction-sections -I/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/target/firmware/include -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs   conftest.c  >&5
configure:3356: $? = 0
configure:3394: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libosmocore"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libosmocore"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "UNKNOWN"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libosmocore UNKNOWN"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "openbsc@lists.osmocom.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libosmocore"
| #define VERSION "UNKNOWN"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3399: error: in `/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/build-target':
configure:3401: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-Os -ffunction-sections -I/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/target/firmware/include -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-elf
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_header_sys_select_h=no
ac_cv_header_sys_socket_h=no
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=arm-elf-gcc
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=arm-elf-strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/missing aclocal-1.14'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='mawk'
CC='arm-elf-gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-Os -ffunction-sections -I/home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/target/firmware/include -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DOXYGEN=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_GB_FALSE=''
ENABLE_GB_TRUE=''
ENABLE_MSGFILE_FALSE=''
ENABLE_MSGFILE_TRUE=''
ENABLE_PLUGIN_FALSE=''
ENABLE_PLUGIN_TRUE=''
ENABLE_SERIAL_FALSE=''
ENABLE_SERIAL_TRUE=''
ENABLE_TALLOC_FALSE=''
ENABLE_TALLOC_TRUE=''
ENABLE_UTILITIES_FALSE=''
ENABLE_UTILITIES_TRUE=''
ENABLE_VTY_FALSE=''
ENABLE_VTY_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HAVE_DOXYGEN_FALSE=''
HAVE_DOXYGEN_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY_DL=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLDFLAGS_OSMOGB=''
LTLDFLAGS_OSMOGSM=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libosmocore'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='openbsc@lists.osmocom.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='libosmocore'
PACKAGE_STRING='libosmocore UNKNOWN'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libosmocore'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='UNKNOWN'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='arm-elf-strip'
SYMBOL_VISIBILITY=''
VERSION='UNKNOWN'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=' -I$(srcdir)'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-elf'
host_alias='arm-elf'
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/robert/OsmocomBB/osmocom-bb/src/shared/libosmocore/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libosmocore"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libosmocore"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "UNKNOWN"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libosmocore UNKNOWN"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "openbsc@lists.osmocom.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "libosmocore"
#define VERSION "UNKNOWN"

configure: exit 77
```